# Assert, Verify and other commands in Selenium WebDriver using C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, automated-tests, selenium-webdriver

I have almost searched every forum/website related to Selenium WebDriver but still unable to find the solution that how to user Assertions and Verifications in Selenium WebDriver using C#.

Here is my code where I just want to put a sample assertion in the code written below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;


namespace Healthfleet
{
    class Login
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"D:\Downloads");
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://test.com/");
            IWebElement username = driver.FindElement(By.Id("username"));
            IWebElement password = driver.FindElement(By.Id("password"));
            username.SendKeys("test@test.test");
            password.SendKeys("test");
            IWebElement loginButton = driver.FindElement(By.Id("Login"));
            loginButton.Click();
        }
    }
}
```

I need to check if username = test or not by using assertion but I am unable to find any Assert class or method.

Am I missing some namespace which contains the Assert class or any other idea?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Thanks @JohnSaunders ... 
I had no idea about this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=download) was required to test this. And you have to add its dll and then add namespace as

`using NUnit.Framework;`

Comment: NUnit or MSTest would do. Take your tests out of a console application, shove them into an empty project. Combine it with TeamCity or Jenkins, and you have a continuous set of automated tests.

Answer (score 2):

Currently you've written the program that manages the browser. If you'll add assertion's from NUnit - it will throw an exceptions in case of failure.

If you want to create tests you should create class without `static void Main(string[] args)` but add some methods marked with `[Test]`. 
I would recommend you to learn the concepts of xUnit-systems and NUnit in particular.